# How do you invoke a sagemaker xgboost endpoint from a chalice app?

Tags: python, web-applications, chalice, amazon-sagemaker

I built a chalice web-app that is hosted in an s3 bucket and calls an xgboost endpoint. I keep getting an error when I invoke the model through the web-app. When I looked into the Lambda log files I discovered my input is not properly decoding. `input_text = app.current_request.raw_body.decode()` What would be the correct code to decode the input from binary so I can pass in a regular string to my endpoint?

Here is the error:

botocore.errorfactory.ModelError: An error occurred (ModelError) when calling the InvokeEndpoint operation: Received client error (415) from model with message "could not convert string to float: user_input=1%".

Here is my index.html file:

```
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
<form method="post" action="<chalice_deployed_http>">

<input type="text" name="user_input"><br>

<input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Here is my app.py file:

```
try:
    from StringIO import StringIO
except ImportError:
    from io import StringIO

from io import BytesIO
import csv
import sys, os, base64, datetime, hashlib, hmac
from chalice import Chalice, NotFoundError, BadRequestError
import boto3


app = Chalice(app_name='<name_of_chalice_app>')
app.debug = True

sagemaker = boto3.client('sagemaker-runtime')

@app.route('/', methods=['POST'], content_types=['application/x-www-form-urlencoded'])
def handle_data():
    input_text = app.current_request.raw_body.decode()

    res = sagemaker.invoke_endpoint(
                    EndpointName='<endpoint_name>',
                    Body=input_text,
                    ContentType='text/csv',
                    Accept='Accept'
                )
    return res['Body'].read().decode()[0]
```

I should be able to pass in a string like this:

'1,4,26,0.076923077,2,3,1,0.611940299,0.7818181820000001,0.40376569,0.571611506,0.12,12,1,0.0,2,1.0,1,2,6,3,1,1,1,1,1,3,1,0.000666667,1,1,2,2,-1.0,0.490196078,-1.0,0.633928571,6.0,145,2,2,1,3,2,2,1,3,2,3,3,-1.0,1,3,1,1,2,1,2,3,1,3,3,1,3,2,3,-1.0,3,3,1,2,2,1,3,3,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,3,0.3497921158934803,0'

and get output like this:

'5'

[When I run it in a jupyter notebook it works.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sb5Nw.jpg)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This worked:

```py
    input_text = app.current_request.raw_body
    d = parse_qs(input_text)
    lst = d[b'user_input'][0].decode()
    res = sagemaker.invoke_endpoint(
                    EndpointName='<name-of-SageMaker-Endpoint>',
                    Body=lst,
                    ContentType='text/csv',
                    Accept='Accept'
                )
```

Answer (score -1):

This blog post shows you how to invoke a SageMaker endpoint from a Chalice app. It uses the built-in image classification algo, but you shouldn't have any trouble adapting it to XGBoost.

https://medium.com/@julsimon/using-chalice-to-serve-sagemaker-predictions-a2015c02b033

Comment: link-only answers can be improved by posting the relevant content here, on StackOverflow. This ensures the answer remains valid in case the link goes down, or the blog post disappears. Moreover, it allows the community to contribute to it